# How to get user's birthday and gender using GoogleSignInAccount?

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I am using GoogleSignInApi to sign in to Google account and then GoogleSignInAccount to retrieve that person's information. Although, GoogleSignInAccount does not include the user's birthday and gender. Other questions suggest using GoogleApiClient and PeopleApi, but both are deprecated.